# how to create convert metrics on KQL

Tags: azure, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying the KQL query currently they gave me Bits/sec out put and I want to Gigabits/sec  on interface speed instead of bit per sec.

[image]

```
  current out put. 

 networkInterfaces_IN       networkInterfaces_OUT
 983,777,544,056             834,528,195,752
 83,777,544,0568             734,528,195,752
```

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, the question was not clear. I did edit the post.. thanks.

Comment: `summarize` doesn't seem to make much sense in that context

Comment: I have added the actual screenshot of the output regarding summarize.

Comment: You are using `summarize` like `distinct`. Why?

Comment: no reason, I have tested  "distinct" also gave me the same out put :)  so how convert this bits/sec to Gigabits/sec  out put is the question easily to read the transmission.

Comment: (1) The point is not whether you use distinct or summarize, it's why are you doing this operation in this first place (2) Gigabits or Gibit? for the 1st divide by 10^9 and for the 2nd by  2^30 or 1024^3. Is that the challenge for you? Doing the division?

Answer (score 1):

- Try to use `format_bytes()` to convert your input from Bits to Gigabits.
- The syntax for the format_bytes() as below, 
  `format_bytes(`*value* [`,`  *precision* [`,`  *units*]]`)`

  **value:** The number which you need to pass as a data in bytes. 
  **precision:** By default it's 0, it's the number of digits which you need to round. (optional) 
  **units:**  It's a result data size which is in string format, like `Bytes, KB, MB, GB, TB`. (optional)

You should be aware of conversion values, like for example 1024 `bytes` is equal to 1 `KB`.

For more information regarding the same, you can refer this below,

1. [format-bytes function](https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language/blob/master/doc/format-bytesfunction.md)
2. [Function to convert bytes into KB MB GB TB PB, etc.,](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Function-to-convert-bytes-into-KB-MB-GB-TB-PB-etc/m-p/468023)
3. [Convert bits per second to gigabit/second](https://www.convertunits.com/from/bits+per+second/to/gigabit/second)